# CSS transition mouse leave doesn't work properly

Tags: css, transition

I am trying to scale and turn down opacity of image it really great work when I enter to the img with cursor but when I leave the img transition doen't work.

Here is my code:

```
#hoverCon:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: all .28s ease-out;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should write

```
#hoverCon img {
  transform  : scale(1);   /* optional */
  opacity    : 1;          /* optional */
  transition : all .28s ease-out;
}

#hoverCon:hover img {
  transform  : scale(1.2);
  opacity    : 0.5;
}
```

Define base properties (optionally) and transition on normal state, then only change properties on `hover`

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JogVVW